# Accessing the localhost from a guest os

Tags: android, linux, localhost, virtualization

I'm developing a web site using php and mysql on linux mint.

now I want to test my page on android environment, so I installed virual box and I installed the Android OS in it.

I also COnfigured the network setting, to connect to the internet from the Android OS.

now I want to access to the localhost where my website is, how can I now the host adresse to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the server IP address with `ifconfig` and use this instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Default setting for accessing host network from inside a virutalbox install is NAT, which sets the gateway to 10.0.2.2, and the nameserver to 10.0.2.3. I.e. you probably want to point your browser to 10.0.2.2.

See: http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.ca/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html